# Spring Data mongo profiling data

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

Is it possible to get profiling data from the spring data mongo db layer.

I know that if I use something like this: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/ then I can get some degree of info out of the application.

I could also custom write an aspect to measure the queries and operations.

However, I am looking for a some built in functionality.  Is there something via JMX or the like?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched around quite a bit and was not about to find any thing so I created my mechanism to track timing and metrics to Mongo.

Given that we are using ELK to gather log and some metrics data, I added an annotation and an aspect to track timings.  I put this on whatever I wanted measure that connects to our mongo methods.  It gather data and puts them in the logs and through Kibana I can see the access under load to Mongo on each type of access.

This is the annotation

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface TimedMethod {

}
```

This is the aspect:

```
@Component()
@Slf4j(topic="com.cisco.services.common.rpil.metrics")
@Aspect
public class TimedMethodAspect {

    @Around("@annotation(com.cisco.services.common.rpil.metrics.TimedMethod) && execution(public * *(..))")
    public Object time(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {

        long start = System.nanoTime();
        String throwableName = null;

        try {

            return pjp.proceed();

        } catch(Throwable t) {
            throwableName = t.getClass().getName();
            throw t;
        } finally {
            long duration = System.nanoTime() - start;
            if (throwableName != null) {
                log.info("Timed [{}]: {} nsecs, with exception [{}]", pjp.getSignature().toString(), duration, throwableName);
            } else {
                log.info("Timed [{}]: {} nsecs", pjp.getSignature().toString(), duration);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically it works like this:

```
@TimedMethod
public Object measureMe() {
...
}
```